# Shutting down fan c++

Tags: c++, windows, api, hardware

For a project, not to harm anybody I was wondering if shutting down your cooling fan is possible using windows API and c++.
There are classes such as [CIM_Fan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-fan#properties) with member functions that should [control speed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setspeed-method-in-class-cim-fan) or even [shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setpowerstate-method-in-class-cim-fan) hardware but I don't even understand how to get these classes into my project. If there is different way without using Windows API, it will help too.
Thanks!

Comment: A dupe of a question about an obsolete platform from more than decade ago? Really?

Comment: I have changed the duplicate to something less dated.